# Can my iPhone photos be viewed by the person I got it from?

Tags: privacy, iphone

I got my phone from a friend, and I wanted to know if anything can be viewed by him. Can he see my photos (and other stuff of course) when he knows the IMEI (and maybe other things) of the phone?

Comment: Has the iPhone ever been rooted? Did you perform a factory reset?

Comment: Im not quite sure what rooted means but I don't think it has. And yeah I think I did.

Answer (score 1):

If your iphone is **not jailbroken**, and you did **a factory reset** (be sure of that) your datas are safe.

For extra precaution you can also verify that all the possible accounts are deleted on the phone : google drive, dropbox, iCloud ...

Comment: If the phone was jail broken in the past and the previous owner installed a spyware in the system before unjailbreaking it, then the malware may in theory survive a factory reset.